How to Modify this FIR filter?
module Modified_FIR_Filter #(
parameter STAGES = 4 // Default STAGES = 4 (2^2)
)
(
input           CLK,
input           RST,
input       [7:0]   Xin,
output      [7:0]   Xin_LED,
output reg  [7:0]   Xout
);

reg [7:0]   STORE [STAGES - 1:0];   // Array to store values
reg [15:0]  ACC;            //Accumulator
integer i;

// Shift register logic
always @ (negedge RST, negedge CLK)
    begin
    if (!RST)
        begin
        for(i = 0; i < STAGES; i = i+1) STORE[i] <= 0;
        end
    else
        begin
        for(i = 0; i < (STAGES-1); i = i+1) STORE[i] <= STORE[i+1];
        STORE[3] <= Xin;
        end
    end

// Accumulation logic
always @*
    begin
    ACC = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < STAGES; i = i+1) ACC = ACC + STORE[i];
    Xout = ACC / STAGES;
    end

assign Xin_LED = Xin; // Pass through Xin to Xin_LED
endmodule

I am trying to modify this FIR filter written in Verilog so that the input (Xin) and output (Xout) are real numbers with a precision of 3 decimal places, and the range goes from 0 to 100. I understand that Verilog primarily works with integer and fixed-point arithmetic, but I need a way to handle real numbers or simulate real-number behavior.
I expected to find a straightforward way to adapt this module for real-valued arithmetic. Specifically, I hoped to use real numbers in Verilog that maintain 3 decimal places of precision, and have the inputs and outputs constrained within 0 to 100.

real would work in simulation, but will not synthesize. Perhaps you should look into fixed-point notation
